# GEE: resampling MODIS LST from 1km to 200km produces gradient

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, modis, resampling

I am trying to resample raster from 1km resolution to 200m using this code:

```
var august = ee.ImageCollection(landsat)
  .filterDate('2019-08-01', '2019-08-30')
  .filterBounds(geometry);
  //Mean temperatre for August
var mean = august.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());


// Get the projection information for a band. test 2
var Day_LST_mean = mean.select('LST_Day_1km_mean');
print('CRS:', Day_LST_mean.projection().crs());
//Resample to 200m
var Day_LST_200m = mean.resample('bilinear').reproject({
    crs: Day_LST_mean.projection().crs(),
    scale: 200
});
//testing resampling
//var mean_200m = mean.resample('bilinear').reproject(crs=crs, scale=200)

Map.addLayer(mean.clip(donbas), imageVisParam, "august mean 1km");
//print(mean);
Map.addLayer(Day_LST_200m.clip(donbas), imageVisParam, "august mean 200m");
```

What I get is a gradient that does not resemble the original.
Can someone clarify where is error in the logic?
Sorry if the question is dumb, I am just beginning my GEE journey.
[image: LST layer original]
[image: Resampled to 200m]

Comment: I think that you may be misunderstanding the 'scale' parameter. The definition is: "If scale is specified, then the projection is scaled by dividing the specified scale value by the nominal size of a meter in the specified projection. If scale is not specified, then the scale of the given projection will be used." Try adjusting the number to 5, instead of 200. If I understand it correctly, then you are merging 200-by-200 pixels, rather than 5-by-5 pixels.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Changes scale to 5.
Now the error is: "august mean 200m: Tile error: Object too large (5160491240 bytes)."

Comment: I am not sure that my initial guess was correct, but I am no GEE expert.

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting the number to 500, instead of 200.